# adding container tags or tracking pixels

Tags: tracking, analytics

How do i add container tags or tracking pixels? I need to add code provided by third party digital media company so I can track conversions.  How is this done on EE?

Answer (score 0):

Add it your template (s) that you use to display content.

Here's some info from the [official docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/design/system/form.html)